# Issue setting the class path in Maven exec plugin when running a Main Class

Tags: java, maven, classpath, integration-testing

I have embedded Jetty in my application. In order to automatically execute my integration tests on my build server I'd like Maven to start my application in the pre-integration-test phase. The integration tests are in another project than the application te be tested, because the tests are of a quite complex nature and should be seperated from production code.

I have tried to set up my application using the Maven exec plugin, but keep running into ClassNotFoundErrors. I use the maven-dependency-plugin to copy all dependencies to target/lib/. Until now, I haven't been able to figure out how to tell the exec plugin to add that lib folder to the class path.

This is my current exec plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.zertificon.managementCenter.adminUi.server.WebApp</mainClass>

                <!-- this does not work: -->
                <classpath>${project.build.directory}/${libFolder}/</classpath>

            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The WebApp class I am trying to run originates from another Project and is installed in the local repository. I would highly apreciate any help.

Comment: Is the WebApp class included in your dependencies?

Comment: Also: are you sure you want to start it with maven. I prefer starting the application under test programmtically from within the test code. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25161236/135673

Comment: Yes, the WebApp class is definitely included

Comment: Also I'd prefer to start the App with maven. I could start it programmatically but that would require a lot of expensive startups / shutdowns in my testing and would cause quite some pain

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? Is it a ClassNotFoundException on WebApp or on some other class? 

I wouldn't be sure that mvn wants to run a main outside of the generated jar file. You could solve this with using the shade plugin to get one fat jar with all the dependencies but maybe you don't want to because of other reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error: I have been using Jetty together with a Selenium Library that itself bundles Jetty, too. This lead to a wrong Jetty Version being loaded wich gave me class not found errors. Go figure.