# Maven running jetty on integration-test stage

Tags: java, maven, jetty, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I use `failsafe` plugin.

So when I type `mvn failsafe:integration-test` it stars my integration tests (which is great).

**But I want my `jetty server` starts on `pre-integration` stage then. What should I do?**

(I don't want launch `mvn verify` since it involves whole cycle running, but `mvn failsafe:integration-test`- it seems it's supposed to work that way)

There are two plugins:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>                                                              <!-- for starting jetty for integration tests -->
    <version>2.16</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <!--<jettyConfig>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/jetty9.xml</jettyConfig>-->
        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
        <stopWait>5</stopWait>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <scanTargets>
            <scanTarget>${project.basedir}/src/main</scanTarget>
            <scanTarget>${project.basedir}/src/test</scanTarget>
        </scanTargets>
        <contextXml>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/jetty-context.xml</contextXml>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</contextPath>
        </webAppConfig>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>                                                         <!-- In the pre-integration-test phase the Jetty server will be started -->
            <goals>
                <goal>run-exploded</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>                                                        <!-- in the "post-integration-phase" it will be stopped -->
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: FYI: post-integration-test is not reached if you just type `integration-test` phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer starting jetty on the fly programmatically inside the test cases. Main reasons for this is:

- the test becomes self contained and not dependent on maven configuration
- it is possible to run the test **as is** in any IDE

Comment: But with maven, integration and unit test become isolated/un-dependable. and it is good for continues integration, - you can start unit test first then integration tests for example. The point about Integration with IDE makes sens though.

Comment: I always separate unit tests and integrations tests in different source trees (or packages) so they are easily separated from within the IDE also. (Run all tests in directory kinda thing....)

Comment: I use that suggestion as an answer. Running jetty server programmatically/directly from integration/unit tests.

Comment: well - for unit tests you shouldn't start jetty - right? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This is the jetty and maven-failsafe-plugin usage manual:

[Maven Failsafe Plugin – Usage](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html#Using_jetty_and_maven-failsafe-plugin)

It provides a sample configuration for integrating Jetty into the integration test life-cycle.

Jetty is started during the `pre-integration-test` phase and stopped during the v`post-integration-test` phase.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.16</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>start-jetty</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <daemon>true</daemon>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>stop-jetty</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

However, it also specifically recommends that you use the `verify` phase:

> The recommendation is that you do not directly invoke the
> pre-integration-test, integration-test or post-integration-test phases
> but that instead you run integration tests by specifying the verify
> phase. [...]
>
> This allows you to set-up your integration test
> environment during the pre-integration-test phase, run your
> integration tests during the integration-test phase, cleanly tear-down
> your integration test environment during the post-integration-test
> phase before finally checking the integration test results and failing
> the build if necessary.

Comment: This works - I implemented a similar setup using the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) to run the integration tests in the `verify` phase.